# MSN XMPP see-other-host empty

Tags: xmpp, msn, msn-messenger

I'm trying to use XMPP to connect with MSN with js.

When I try to connect to "messenger.live.com" I send

```
<body rid='2126688061' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='messenger.live.com' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

and I get

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" type="terminate" condition="remote-stream-error">
    <stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
        <see-other-host xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"></see-other-host>
    </stream:error>
</body>
```

I do not understand why no alternative host is offered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Microsofts way of load balancing :(
After connecting the stream they redirect you to another host. You have to close the existing stream and initiate another stream to the given host.
I always have seen there another host. Can you get more logs from your BOSH proxy with the RAW data?
Does your BOSH proxy support this redirection feature?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was usign as BOSH connection handler the metajack.im url given in the book Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery. Now I'm struggling with the installation of punjab in my Windows machine, so I can get more information. Whenever I finish with this installation, I will let you know if that helped or not. Do you know if there is a easy way to configure openfire to work as BOSH connection manager for other services like live messenger?

Comment: AFAIK punjab does not support the see-other-host redirection.
Openfire does not support BOSH routing to other domains.

Comment: Then, do you have any idea that how I can solve this? without using openfire or punjab

Comment: either use something else than BOSH, or extend punjab to support the see-other-host feature.